# Python 2.7 : How to remove the Tkinter logo from my GUI app using PySimpleGUI27?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, icons, pysimplegui

I used the PySimpleGUI27 framework which is wrapped around tkinter to create gui in python. My GUI works fine but it comes up with tkinter icon on top left as the pic below :

[image]

Is there any way to remove this icon in PySimpleGUI27 framework? I dont seem to find answer in PySimpleGUI27  cookbook.

Update :

I got below error after trying this

I got below error in line `button, values_dict = window.Read()` after trying this `window = sg.Window('A2L Parser', default_element_size=(40, 1), icon='C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\index.png').Layout(layout)`

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
couldn't recognize image data
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3331, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3377, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\PySimpleGUI27.py", line 3694, in SetIcon
    wicon = tkinter.PhotoImage(data=icon)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\PySimpleGUI27.py", line 6105, in StartupTK
    my_flex_form.SetIcon(my_flex_form.WindowIcon)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\PySimpleGUI27.py", line 3685, in Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\PySimpleGUI27.py", line 3760, in Read
    self.Show()
  File "C:\Users\anubhav.jhalani\Documents\A2L Parser\A2L parser_29_04\A2L parser\run.py", line 26, in <module>
    button, values_dict = window.Read()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
```

Comment: Try adding `disable_minimize=True` when creating the main window.

Comment: It worked!! Is there any way to replace this icon with my icon?

Comment: Try setting `icon='/path/to/your/icon'` and remove `disable_minimize`.

Comment: use '\\' instead of '\'.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks man!

Comment: You can also place an 'r' in front of your filename string:
icon=r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\index.png'

Also, the python 2 version of tkinter tends to like GIF files the most.